# Issue with geoIP code

Tags: magento-1.9, geoip

I have installed the OpenStream geoIp extension that pulls data from MaxMind database and I have been using this code for years to hide prices in countries that are not allowed:

```
            $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
                    if ($geoIP->isCountryAllowed()) {
                     ...
                     }
```

Now this is no longer working. Allowed countries are only UK, US and Canada. I want to hide prices for all other countries, but if I echo the country code, it shows US. I am using a VPN to test. Also if I try to update the GeoIP db I get banned for hours. Has anything changed? ANy pointer is very welcome.

Comment: which API you used to get groip data?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I am using Openstream extension that pulls data from the Maxmind database.

Comment: Share the code to get information from that database that you do.

Comment: I will have to copy the whole extension. The project code is available on github [link](https://github.com/ProxiBlue/geoip)

Comment: Can you tell me, does are you not able to get data from magento configruation? or from Maxmind database? And where above code you write? give me file path.

Comment: Whatever country I connect from using a VPN, if I echo the country code, it returns "US" which is wrong. I used that code above in the view.phtml file and list.phtml files to hide the prices and add to cart buttons. From the backend I set the allowed countries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93143/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-shakamal).

Comment: if I echo the country code, it returns "US" which is wrong.----- Does Maxmind return wrong or magento?

Answer (score 0):

I also installed this plugin many years ago on my Magento V1 store and just recently I got complaints that certain content I had been hiding from other countries was now being viewed.  I'm not sure what happened it just stopped working.  Did you find the issue on your end?

Answer (score 0):

MaxMind GeoIP Lite has been discontinued (https://support.maxmind.com/geolite-legacy-discontinuation-notice/) so it is no longer possible to synchronise the DB and, as a consequence, some IPs are not detected correctly.